# load balancer and Circuit Breaker

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I search to use spring boot, spring-cloud-gateway, netflix eureka.

Is there anything to do to have a load balancer and circuit breaker for micro-service instance?

I found few information ex ribbon when spring gateway is used instead of zuul.

Actually I have an application for the gateway, another for eureka, another for thymeleaf client
security is not yet choose, probabley jwt

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you are asking. https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.SR1/single/spring-cloud.html#hystrix and https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.SR1/single/spring-cloud.html#_loadbalancerclient_filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Spring Cloud Gateway, you can currently use the [Hystrix Gateway Filter](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/spring-cloud-gateway.html#hystrix).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-it-Works). It is extremely good for microservices and aligns well with Spring cloud stack. Also, take a look at [Feign](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign), due to its simplistic approach to communication between microservices and integration with hystrix and ribbon.